# i am using python 3.9.13 and in pip version 22.2.1 , an error occurred in the subprocess, how to fixed?

Tags: python-3.x

Collecting aiofiles
Using cached aiofiles-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting aiohttp
Using cached aiohttp-3.8.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting asyncio
Using cached asyncio-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting dnspython
Using cached dnspython-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (269 kB)
Collecting ffmpeg-python
Using cached ffmpeg_python-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting gitpython
Using cached GitPython-3.1.27-py3-none-any.whl (181 kB)
Collecting hachoir
Using cached hachoir-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (647 kB)
Collecting heroku3
Using cached heroku3-5.1.4.tar.gz (160 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [12 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 14, in 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 14, in 
from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 24, in 
from setuptools.depends import Require
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in 
from .py33compat import Bytecode
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/py33compat.py", line 54, in 
unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape)
AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: Can you add details like what command or steps that shows how this error occurred ?

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: please share your requirement.txt file.

Comment: https://github.com/TeamYukki/YukkiMusicBot/blob/master/requirements.txt

Comment: Please help....

Comment: I have a problem here

Comment: the git repo says " Not needed anymore /:"  are you sure you want to install it.
there might be a chance that that version is not compatible in installation. 
But, if you still want to install.. try installing one by one.. and resolve the package error.
eg. try installing aiofiles first.

Comment: ffmpeg-python not compatible

Comment: look for a compatible version of ffmpeg-python and add that version in requirement.txt or install manually. try this:  pip install python-ffmpeg

Comment: Must update setup wheel